# "suppôt" in Pascal

Tags: vocabulaire

A student of mine chose to translate [this pensée](https://journals.openedition.org/studifrancesi/38802) of Pascal's:

> La théologie est une science, mais en même temps combien est-ce de sciences? Un homme est **un suppôt**, mais si on l’anatomise que sera-ce? la tête, le cœur, l’estomac, les veines, chaque veine, chaque portion de veine, le sang, chaque humeur de sang. Une ville, une campagne, de loin c’est une ville et une campagne, mais à mesure qu’on s’approche, ce sont des maisons, des arbres, des tuiles, des feuilles, des herbes, des fourmis, des jambes de fourmis, à l’infini. Tout cela s’enveloppe sous le nom *campagne*.

We had a hard time figuring out what is meant by *un suppôt* here. On the one hand, he  contrasts it with all the parts, hence something like "a whole, a sum, an individual", etc. But on the other hand, there doesn't appear to be a definition of *suppôt* that "suppots" that reading.

If he wants to say "Man is an agent (servant?) [of God]" or something to that effect, is he simply bringing in an idea from some other argument not explicitly connected to this thought? Or is there another way to interpret *suppôt* ?

Comment: Je recopie la définition d'Antidote, peut-être que ce serait utile. Définitions de suppôt, nom masculin locution Serviteur d’un vil personnage. VIEUX – Subalterne. Locution (1) _suppôt de Satan​  ou suppôt du diable_​ Personne méchante. // vil (Antidote) SOUTENU Qui inspire le mépris ; méprisable. _Un être abject et vil. Une action vile._

Comment: @Oreste Oui, j'ai vu ça, mais comment peut-on réconcilier cette acception avec le sens voulu dans le passage ?

Comment: He says **un suppôt mais blah blah blabh**. Man is a contemptible or abject being (mind qualities)**but** what do you obtain from his anatomical parts? Just the parts, right?  It's that old mind/body dichotomy. Le problème esprit-corps. He was a dualist like Descartes.

Comment: Theology and science are like contemptible  man and his parts. Not unified. Whereas town and country form a unified whole.

Comment: @Lambie Then if I understand right, he uses *suppôt* because that's what man is in the broad view of theology?

Comment: Yes, in his view. In any case,  man is vile in spirit, on the one hand, and a collection of body parts, on the other.

Comment: Euh... À mon avis, soit _un assistant de Dieu_, soit _une aide du mal_ A. − HIST. Personne qui, appartenant à un corps, à une compagnie, à titre secondaire, remplissait certaines fonctions pour le service de ce corps; celui qui en secondait un autre ou remplissait des fonctions de subalterne. Suppôt de l'Université. (TLFi) Mais j'avoue parcourir rapidement le lien (dans la question). En bref, un être humain ayant une âme ?

Comment: Please see this Cambridge Companion to Pascal which defines suppôt as: man as monster///https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cambridge_Companion_to_Pascal/ZMUIi0O43_sC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=supp%C3%B4t+%2B+pascal&pg=PA130&printsec=frontcover //the next paragraph mentions dualism....

Comment: @Lambie Your statement about what the Cambrige says is inaccurate. It is the contradictory coexistence of the two natures which constitute man as a monster, not suppôt.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pascal_s_Apology_for_Religion/9_5OxD19W7MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=supp%C3%B4t+%2B+pascal&pg=PA20&printsec=frontcover an an individual substance from the Latin suppositum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le littré indique, comme sens possible :

> Terme de philosophie. Ce qui sert de fondement, de soutien, de sujet.

Et cite ensuite comme exemple la phrase de Pascal donnée dans la question !

Comment: I checked in my critical edition (Michel Le Guern), and there's an endnote on *suppôt* that reads: "Terme scolastique. Un homme est un sujet, une unité pour la pensée." So this seems to be the best theory.

Answer (score 2):

*Suppôt* n'a pas toujours eu la connotation négative qu'il a aujourd'hui, liée à *suppôt de Satan*.

Étymologiquement, c'est quelqu'un qui est "posté (situé) dessous", soumis à une autorité, un vassal, un sujet (du roi).

Dans le texte de Pascal, je le lit simplement comme un synonyme de personne :

> Un homme est une personne (comme les autres), mais si on en étudie l'anatomie,...

cf. [Cotgrave](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/cotgrave/suppost):

> Quelque bon suppost vous le dira : *Some good fellow or other will tell it you.*

Edit: Le sens a retenir est en fait celui présenté dans les deux autres réponses ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49887/1109) & [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/49890/1109)), bien que la différence ne soit pas si grande pour ce qui est de l'interprétation de la phrase.

L'étymologie reste identique (*suppositum* : placé dessous) mais, dans le document *[Faut-il réutiliser les concepts linguistiques du passé ? Un regard rétrospectif sur le prédicat](https://journals.openedition.org/pratiques/3791)*, on montre que mot *suppôt* a été opposé au mot *appôt* (*appositum*). Il est décrit comme une abréviation probable de *supponere personam verbo*, « mettre la personne sous le verbe » ou « tenir lieu de personne pour le verbe ».

On retrouve aussi le sens de personne dans une édition des Pensées de Pascal commentée par le philosophe Léon Brunschwicg:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> [...] Par ailleurs, suppôt a désigné (XIVe s. *suppost*), encore à
> l'époque classique, ce qui sert de base à qqch., en philosophie (av.
> 1662) la substance avec ses accidents ; dans cette acception sortie
> d'usage, le sens interfère avec celui de *support*, apparenté à
> *portare* et non à *ponere*.
>
> [ Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, sup. A. Rey, Le
> Robert, 2011, « suppôt ». ]

Si c'était l'idée de [*support*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/support#Fran%C3%A7ais) auquel référait l'emploi dans le texte, alors ce sont des idées comme *base*, *médium* etc. qui pourront être utiles.

Comment: Interesting — I hadn't drawn the possible connection to *support* as in *support papier*, etc.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'm only familiar with _suppôt de Satan_ so I had to check, because otherwise I'd read it somewhat like you did, an _intermediary_, a _lackey_, something. When I read the DHLF I also noted it says before 1662, which is the year Pascal died. Seemingly that usage died along with him.

Comment: HIST. Personne qui, appartenant à un corps, à une compagnie, à titre secondaire, remplissait certaines fonctions pour le service de ce corps; celui qui en secondait un autre ou remplissait des fonctions de subalterne. Suppôt de l'Université I think in that sense, it is an assistant.

Comment: This content can be remixed to provide further content. If so, please provide adequate reference (to the DHLF). Thank you.